# Dynamic value initialization in Array in java

Tags: java

In my code I have one vairable:

```
public Edge[] adjacencies;
```

now for initialization array is something like this:

```
     v0.adjacencies = new Edge[] {
        new Edge(v1, distance[0][1]),
        new Edge(v2, distance[0][2]),
        new Edge(v3, distance[0][3]),
        new Edge(v4, distance[0][4]),
        new Edge(v5, distance[0][5]),
        new Edge(v6, distance[0][6]),
        new Edge(v7, distance[0][7]) 
        };
```

but I want to give dynamic initialization something like this:

```
 v0.adjacencies = new Edge[] {
    for(int i=1;i<8;i++)    
         new Edge("v"+i, distance[0][i]); 
 };
```

Comment: Sounds like `v[i]` needs to be an array, instead of `v0, v1, v2` etc.

Comment: I certainly doubt if `v*` are strings, as assumed by everybody who has posted the answer. All those `v1, v2..` seem to be some class(I guess Vertex) objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this dynamically is to create the array with the variable length.

```
length = 8; 
v0.adjecencies = new Edge[length];
for(int i=1;i<length;i++)    
  v0.adjecencies[i-1] = new Edge("v"+i, distance[0][i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vertex[] vertices = {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7};
v0.adjacencies = new Edge[7];
for(int i=1;i<8;i++) {   
  v0.adjacencies[i-1] = new Edge(vertices[i-1], distance[0][i]); 
}
```

Try this.

**Update**: I assume those v1, v2, ... are objects of class Vertex (whatever you call it) and update the code accordingly.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException is coming

Comment: after that when I am calling from one function   `computePaths(v0);` NullPointerException is coming

Comment: @user2908533 Updated. See if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
v0.adjacencies = new Edge[7];
for(int i = 1; 1 < 8; i++)
{
    v0.adjacencies[i - 1] = new Edge("v"+i, distance[0][i]); 
}
```

I'm assuming that `v1`, `v2`, etc are strings of the form `v1`, `v2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the `java.util package,` specifically the `ArrayList class`. It has methods such as `.add() .remove() .indexof() .contains() .toArray(),` and more

Answer (score 0):

Forget all about your variables `v1`, `v2` and so on.  Just keep them all in an array to start with.

```
Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    vertices[i] = new Vertex();
}

vertices[0].adjacencies = new Edge[7];
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    vertices[0].adjacencies[i - 1] = new Edge(vertices[i], distance[0][i]);
}
```